# How to insert into hive table, partitioned by date reading from temp table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning, hive-query

I have a Hive temp table without any partitions which has the data required. I want to select this data and insert into another table partitioned by date. I tried following techniques with no luck.

**Source table schema**

```
 CREATE TABLE cls_staging.cls_billing_address_em_tmp
( col1 string,
 col2 string,
col3 string);
```

Destination table :

```
CREATE TABLE cls_staging.cls_billing_address_em_tmp
    ( col1 string,
     col2 string,
    col3 string) 
    PARTITIONED BY (
       curr_date string) 
      STORED AS ORC;
```

Query for inserting into destination table :

```
insert overwrite table cls_staging.cls_billing_address_em_tmp partition (record_date)  select col1, col2, col3, FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) from myDB.mytbl;
```

ERROR

```
Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column
```

2nd

```
insert overwrite table cls_staging.cls_billing_address_em_tmp partition (record_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))  select col1, col2, col3 from myDB.mytbl;
```

ERROR :

```
cannot recognize input near 'FROM_UNIXTIME' '(' 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP'
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238583/hive-dynamic-partitioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st Switch-on dynamic partitioning and non-strict mode:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table cls_staging.cls_billing_address_em_tmp partition (record_date)  
select col1, col2, col3, current_timestamp from myDB.mytbl;
```

2nd: Do not use `unix_timestamp()` for this purpose, because it will generate many different timestamps, use `current_timestamp` constant, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081191/2700344

Comment: Can we choose its format as well ?

Comment: @Saawan Sure. Specify format like this: select date_format(current_timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS');